# Using T-SQL table variables with the MS SQL Server Driver for PHP

Tags: php, t-sql

I have a stored procedure written in T-SQL and want to use a table variable.

Here is a simple example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test   
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(       
        id int, data nvarchar(128)
    )

    INSERT INTO @tempTable (id, data)
        SELECT id, data FROM otherTable

    SELECT * FROM @tempTable 
END
```

I create the procedure on MS SQL Server 2008 running on Windows Server 2003.

If I call the procedure within MS SQL Server Management Studio (Version 10.0.2531.0) I get the correct results.

Here is my problem:
If I call the statement from the [PHPDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296173.aspx) I get **no results**.

This seems to be the case whenever I use temporary table variables..

Here is the PHP code:

```
$dataBaseConnectionInfo = array(
    'UID'      => $this->loginName,
    'PWD'      => $this->password,
    'Database' => $this->databaseName
);

$serverHandle = sqlsrv_connect(
    $this->serverAddress,
    $dataBaseConnectionInfo
);

$queryResult = sqlsrv_query($serverHandle, 'EXECUTE test');
$fetchedRows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
var_dump($fetchedRows);
```

Thx in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of the stored procedure